# Either/Or Constraint re-formulation

Tags: linear-programming, constraint-programming

I have the following Either/Or constraint, and I want to re-formulate that constraint into other compatible constraints to build a standard linear programming problem.
The Either/Or constraint that I have is:

$y=1$, if $x \gt 0$

or

$y=0$, if $x \lt 0 $

Thank you very much.

Comment: That is not possible. The set of feasible pairs $(x,y)$ for your constraint is not convex.

Comment: Ok thank you Gerw. Then I must find a range for $x$ to make this possible.

Comment: What is your objective function ? Has the objective function to be maximized or minimized ? And how your variables are defined ? Posting the whole model would be helpful.